# Erro em fazer pesquisa por nome Access ASP.NET C#

Tags: c#, banco-de-dados, asp.net, microsoft-access, crud

Estou com um erro a pesquisa por nome(valor digitado pelo usuário) no banco de dados    access 
ele fala que os valores no dentro do parâmetros está nulo. Segue o codigo. 
      Pessoa.cs responsavel pela lógica do banco.

```
public Contato obterCadastroPorNome(string Nome)
{
    ConexaoDAL conexaoAccess = null;
    try
    {
        conexaoAccess = new ConexaoDAL();
        conexaoAccess.AbrirConexao();
        OleDbCommand ComandoAccess = new OleDbCommand("select*from Contato where NOME=@NOME", conexaoAccess.ConexaoAccess);
        ComandoAccess.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NOME", Nome);
        conexaoAccess.ComandoDataReaderAccess.Read();
        return null;

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw new Exception("Erro ao pesquisar clientes" + ex.Message);
    }
    finally
    {
        conexaoAccess.FecharConexao();
    }
} // metodo para pesquisar cadastro por id 

public List<Contato> ListaDeContato()
{
    ConexaoDAL conexaoAccess = null;
    try
    {
        conexaoAccess.AbrirConexao();
        OleDbCommand ComandoAccess = new OleDbCommand("select * from Contato ", conexaoAccess.ConexaoAccess);
        conexaoAccess.ComandoDataReaderAccess = ComandoAccess.ExecuteReader();
        List<Contato> lista = new List<Contato>();
        while (conexaoAccess.ComandoDataReaderAccess.Read())
        {
            lista.Add(new Contato(conexaoAccess.ComandoDataReaderAccess));
        }
        return lista;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw new Exception("Erro ao pesquisar Lista de clientes " + ex.Message);
    }
    finally
    {
        conexaoAccess.FecharConexao();
    }
```

#### Contato.cs

```
namespace DAL.Model
{
    public class Contato
    {
        public int Codigo { get; private set; }
        public string Nome, Email, Fone;

        public Contato(string nome, string email, string fone)
        {
            Nome = nome;
            Email = email;
            Fone = fone;
        }
        public Contato(int codigo, string nome, string email, string fone)
        {
            Codigo = codigo;
            Nome = nome;
            Email = email;
            Fone = fone;
        }

        public Contato(OleDbDataReader comandoDataReader)
        {
            Codigo = Convert.ToInt32(comandoDataReader["CODIGO"]);
            Nome = Convert.ToString(comandoDataReader["NOME"]);
            Email = Convert.ToString(comandoDataReader["EMAIL"]);
            Fone = Convert.ToString(comandoDataReader["FONE"]);
        }

    }
}


public void btnPesquisar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    garregarInfo();
}

public void garregarInfo()
{
    try
    {
        string NOME = Convert.ToString(txtPesquisar.Text);
        Pessoa pessoa = new Pessoa();
        Contato contato = pessoa.obterCadastroPorNome(NOME);
        if (contato != null)
        {
            pnlPesquisa.Visible = true;
            txtNovoNome.Text = contato.Nome;
        }
        else
        {
            Message.Text = "Registro não encontrado";
        }

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw new Exception(Message.Text = ex.Message);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Como a própria mensagem de erro já diz, não é possível parar um parâmetro `null` pro método `AddWithValue`. Você vai precisar fazer uma validação e se a string for nula, enviar o valor como `""` (string vazia).

```
ComandoAccess.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NOME", Nome ?? "");
```

Comment: é melhor verificar se a variável Nome é null e dar um return (ou um erro para o usuário preencher o campo)  logo, ir ao banco fazer uma buscar por "" não tem sentido.

Comment: Acho que é mais erro na *query* dele. Nos comentários ele diz que quer buscar todos quando for null ou vazio. Então, ele deveria trocar o `=` por `like`.